# Kotlin list extension function

Tags: list, kotlin, generics, concatenation, kotlin-extension

I have an extension function shown below

```
infix fun List<Int>.sumList(that: List<Int>) =
    this.zip(that, Int::plus)
```

I am now trying to make this extension function generic so that it works on list of integers as well as float and double.

`listOf(1,2,3).sumList(listOf(10,20,30))` gives me [11, 22, 33]

Below is my attempt of writing the same extension function using generics

```
inline infix fun <reified T: Number> List<T>.sumListNew(that: List<T>): List<T> = when {
    T is Double -> this.zip(that, Double::plus)
    else -> this.zip(that, Int::plus)
}
```

However I am getting compiler error at T saying type parameter is not an expression.
Can someone help me resolve this error and also reason for getting this error?

Comment: What is the point of making this function generic if you then have to provide separate implementations for each subtype anyway? I think it would be better to just create multiple overloads.

Comment: @broot One (possibly questionable) reason is so you can have only one `sum` method, instead of `sumInts`, `sumDoubles`, and so on. Though that can also be solved by using `@JvmName("sumInts")`, `@JvmName("sumDoubles")`, etc.

Comment: I think you have to do it like this: `when(T::class) { Double::class -> (this as List<Double>).zip(that as List<Double>, Double::plus) as List<T>`. So a lot of boilerplate. But still, I think you should use overloads and yes, with `@JvmName`. This function is unusable from Java anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you may do it this way by having one sum method and just overriding the plus operator for Number:

```
operator fun Number.plus(a : Number) : Number{
    return when(this::class){
        Int::class -> this.toInt() + a.toInt()
        Double::class -> this.toDouble() + a.toDouble()
        else -> error("Data Type not found!")
    }
}

inline infix fun <reified T: Number> List<T>.sumListNew(that: List<T>): List<T>{
    return this.zip(that,Number::plus) as List<T>
}
```